# How do I extract data from a file in haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I need to open a file, read the first line, convert the number to an Integer X, and read an array of X integers from the second line. Can it be done in Haskell?

The following code:

```
main = do
  val1 <- getLine
  val2 <- getLine
  print val1
  print map read (words val2) :: Int
```

Gives this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(String -> a1) -> [String] -> Int'
            with actual type `IO ()'
```

Comment: Read the two lines (see any tutorial for this), then `map read (words secondLine) :: [Int]` should do (if you want better error handling on invalid input than crashing the program, switch to `reads` or other total functions instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to laziness, you usually do not worry about reading line by line, getContents is fine. Though, in your case, maybe calling getLine twice is not that bad.

Your code is good (although it doesn't take only X numbers from the list), it's just your type which is not right. This line should get you going:

```
print (map read (words val2) :: [Int])
```

You will probably want to use val1 as well, like so:

```
print $ take (read val1) (map read (words val2) :: [Int])
```